# How to implode(back to original) Pandas characters to words separated by NaN rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
| characters | result |
|:----------:|:------:| 
| b          | TP    |
| a          | TP    | 
| t          | FN    | 
| NaN        | None  | 
| c          | TN    |  
| o          | FP    |  
| p          | TP    |
```

I exploded it before from being "bat" and "cop". Each word is separated by a NaN row. I would like to bring them back into a DataFrame format like this:

```
| characters | result | word |
|:----------:|:----- :|:----:|
| b          | TP     | bat  |
| a          | TP     | bat  |
| t          | FN     | bat  |
| NaN        | None   | None |
| c          | TN     | cop  |
| o          | FP     | cop  |
| p          | TP     | cop  |
```

Edit:
Please ignore the result column. It's just the `characters` and `word` that matters here. The original dataframe consisted of the `word` column and applied pandas `explode()` to get the `characters` column.

Comment: So the row in result is nan or None (the value in Python)?

Comment: Can you provide the original dataframe?

Comment: @mozway the original dataframe is the second table without the `result` column

Comment: @DaniMesejo don't mind the result column. i just want to get the original word back. In fact, i think it would be better if i hadn't included it. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom group to identify the consecutive non NaN values, then join and map to the original dataframe:

```
m = df['characters'].isna()
group = (m!=m.shift()).cumsum().mask(m)
to_map = df.groupby(group)['characters'].apply(lambda g: ''.join(g))
df['word'] = group.map(to_map)
```

output:

```
  characters result word
0          b     TP  bat
1          a     TP  bat
2          t     FN  bat
3        NaN   None  NaN
4          c     TN  cop
5          o     FP  cop
6          p     TP  cop
```